# Replace function with text in specific cell - Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I tried to use the following code to replace the current cell formula with **test** text instead.

```
function replace_content() {

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var cellRange = sheet.getActiveCell();
cellRange.setValue("test")
return true
)
```

But something goes wrong and I get this error msg

```
Error
Exception: You do not have permission to call setValue (line 59).
```

Please advice.

Comment: How are you executing this function?

Comment: The function runs for me just fine, I can't reproduce your results.

Comment: By writing the function inside the cell.

Comment: Oh your using it as a Custom function.  Well you should check the restrictions for custom functions: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

Comment: You cannot use set [ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services)  It generally pays to read the documentation.

Comment: Understand, Is there any other way to deal with the instruction? for example to detect which cell is changed and replace only this one?

Comment: I thought to create another script that use "on edit" trigger but I saw this "cript executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run. For example, calling Range.setValue() to edit a cell does not cause the spreadsheet's onEdit trigger to run." and that mean it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

This function runs for me with no problems:

```
function replace_content() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var cellRange = sheet.getActiveCell();
  cellRange.setValue("test")
  return true;
}
```